How to create and add an app icon to an iOS project contained in a Kotlin Multiplatform project?
Coming from Android and Linux and knowing very little about Xcode, I have added an iOS project as a module to a Kotlin Multiplatform project by copying and modifying an example from the JetBrains Compose Multiplatform repository. In fact it was iosApp from examples/interop/ios-compose-in-uikit.
This simple iOS project was presumably not created with an Xcode wizard and it contains no default asset catalog.
How do I create and add an app icon for the resulting iOS app?
Naively creating a directory called Assets.xcassets and adding a file called AppIcon.png to it, does not work.
The directions in Apple's documentation and this recent blog assume that the default asset catalog already exists.
The accepted answer to an overlapping question says to 'Add Asset catalog to framework target as usual via New File... > Resources'. This leaves out too many steps for me to follow, as either it assumes too much familiarity with Xcode, or the Xcode interface has changed since 2020.

Using Xcode (e.g. version 16.1) and Gimp:

If no (default) asset catalog exists in the iOS project, create one with Xcode:
File -> New -> File from Template... -> (Resource) Asset Catalog -> Next -> (Save as: Assets.xcassets) Create

Create a graphics file, e.g. AppIcon.png of (NB!) 1024 x 1024 pixels. Starting e.g. from an .svg file, open it in Gimp with the required dimensions, then export it as a .png. (A Google Playstore 512 x 512 .png file will not be accepted.)

In Xcode, select Assets.xassets (maybe the one created in the first step) in the Project Navigator. Then select AppIcon in the tab on the right, and double click on the block labelled 'Any Appearance'. Use the file picker that appears, to find and accept the file AppIcon.png created in the second step.

Launch the app from Xcode on a simulator or device with the 'Start the active scheme' arrow button. Wait for the debugger to attach to the target (done when the message at the top right says 'Running [app] on [target]'), then stop the app with the block button to the left of the arrow button.


Check on the simulator or device to ensure that the default iOS app icon has been replaced with the one created in the second step.
